# Is $k[x,x^{-1}]$ a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and we consider the ring $k[x,x^{-1}]\cong k[x,y]/(xy-1)$. It is clear that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is a UFD (unique factorization domain) but is $k[x,x^{-1}]$ a PID (principal ideal domain)?

Comment: You can also view it as the localization of $k[x]$ at powers of $x$, whence the duplicate gives you your answer.

Comment: Localization of PID is a PID